# Count paydays left in year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I want to count the number of days that

1. Occur between now and the end of the year (i.e 31 December), and
2. That fall on either the 15th or last day of the month (30th for April, June, September, November; 31st for January, March, May, July, August, October, December; 28th for February).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If a month has 31 days do you still want the 30th day of that month included?  Also, how about February?

Comment: can you use VBA or just function?

Comment: Yep, Dec 31st is included. I'd like to use pure Excel functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like it might work (though I think it could likely be tidied up and I'm sure there's a better way...)

```
=(12-MONTH(TODAY()))*2 
+ IF(DAY(TODAY())<15,2,
        IF(DAY(TODAY())<DAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1)-1),1,0))
```

(12-MONTH(TODAY()))*2  : Two days for each full remaining month

Plus 2 days if before the 15th

or

Plus 1 day if 15th or later and not the last day of the current month

Comment: + 1 Nice one for all the month ends. Returns 10 as it should. :)

Comment: It works like a dream. I changed the less than to less than or equals to (last line of your code sample) so I could account for the current day being on the 15th.

Answer (score 2):

A variant which avoids array formulas.

**`1. For your question as asked`**

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW()))+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),12,31)-TODAY()+1)))={15}))+(13-MONTH(TODAY()))`
= 10

**`2. For my initial interpretation which was to count any days corresponding to a certain day of the month`**

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW()))+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),12,31)-TODAY()+1)))={15,30}))`
=10

whereas

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW()))+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),12,31)-TODAY()+1)))={15,31}))`
=8

and

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW()))+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),12,31)-TODAY()+1)))={15,30,31}))`
=13

To change the days required simply change the `{15,30}` component
ie
={1,2,12,15,31}
to count all days that fall on the 1st, 2nd, 12th, 15th and 31st etc

*This formula will handle leap years*

Comment: + 1 Nice use of `SUMPRODUCT`. The formula returns 8 as it should.

Comment: brettdj. It is giving unexpected result for {15,30,31}. It should return 10 or am I missing something?

Comment: @SiddharthRout It should be 13 - which it is :) (all months from Aug - Dec have at least 30 days, so 8 (from prior question) +5 = 13)

Comment: Ha Ha Ha... It is still 6:39 AM here :D

Comment: What's with the `--` in the formula?

Comment: @Enigmativity corercion to convert a TRUE into 1 by multiplying by `-1*-1`.

Comment: There might be some boundary conditions that don't work. E.g. in formula 1, `NOW()` as 15 Dec 2012 returns 1 (as if the 15th should not count), but `NOW()` as 31 Dec 2012 also returns 1 (as if the 31st should count). It's not clear if the OP wants to include the current date in the result, but it does't seem the result should depend on whether `TODAY()` is EOM or an arbitrary mid-month day.

Comment: @andyholaday The more flexible Formula 2 does exclude the boundary condition for 31 Dec 2012 (ie returns 0). I will update the non-array part of formula 1 for consistency. You raise a fair point that the current date condition should have been specified

Answer (score 0):

This should work on any day of any year in any version of Excel until year 2078 (much longer in Excel 2007 or later).

```
=SUM(IF(DAY(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,TODAY(),0,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),12,31)-TODAY()+1)))={1,16},1,0))
```

Note I'm checking for day = 1 or 16 on an offset of 1 day (the idea was to get around varying end-of-month `DAY()` values).

{Array formula... Press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to commit}

[addendum]

If you do not want to include the current day (e.g., say today is 15 August), use this instead:

```
=SUM(IF(DAY(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,TODAY()+1,0,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),12,31)-TODAY()+1)))={1,16},1,0))
```

P.s. I tested on all dates from today through leap day 2016 and beyond and it works a treat. All this does is test row numbers treated as a date serial by the `DAY()` function to see if they are 1 or 16, but the serial is offset by +1 so it's really checking to see if `DAY()` is [last day of whatever month] or 15. If the result is true, add 1, else add 0.

---

[more addenda]

Here are *non-array* versions that otherwise work the same way:

Includes the current day:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(DAY(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,TODAY(),0,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),12,31)-TODAY()+1)))={1,16}))
```

Excludes the current day

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(DAY(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,TODAY(),0,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),12,31)-TODAY()+1)))={1,16}))
```